# How to use Boost.Python in Eclipse running on Linux Mint 18?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, boost, boost-python

The objective is to compile a C++ program with Boost.Python in Eclipse on the OS on Linux Mint 18. In particularly, we want to run the template program:

```
#include<boost/version.hpp>
#include<boost/python.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "My first boost program with version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This personally took me quite a while to get working, so the tutorial below should serve as a one-stop-shop reference for anyone in a similar situation. Note on software used:

- Boost version: 1.62.0
- Python version: 2.7.12
- OS: Linux Mint 18 Xfce 64-bit
- Eclipse version: CDT 9.1.0 for Eclipse Neon.1

Answer (score 3):

**Installing Eclipse CDT**

1. Make sure that you have Java installed. For the Java JDK (if you want to also develop Java programs), run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install default-jdk
   ```

   To simply run Java programs (such as Eclipse), you can install the lighter Java JRE:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install default-jre
   ```

   Both JDK and JRE will work, but JDK takes up more space.
2. Go to [CDT download webpage](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neon1) and download the Linux 64-bit file `eclipse-cpp-neon-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`
3. Assuming you downloaded the file in `~/Downloads/`, run the following command to unpack ("install") Eclipse into the `/opt/` directory:

   ```
   sudo tar zxvf ~/Downloads/eclipse-cpp-neon-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt/
   ```
4. To create a desktop launcher icon, run

   ```
   sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   and in the text editor copy-paste:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Eclipse
   Type=Application
   Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Comment=Integrated Development Environment
   NoDisplay=false
   Categories=Development;IDE;
   Name[en]=Eclipse
   ```

You now have Eclipse installed, but you don't need to run it yet, just keep reading and following the instructions :)

**Installing Boost**

The instructions are more or less given [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), but for the sake of cohesion I write them here.

1. Download [boost_1_62_0.tar.gz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.62.0/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz)
2. Assuming you downloaded the file into `~/Downloads/`, run the following command to unpack Boost into the `/usr/include/` directory:

   ```
   sudo tar zxvf ~/Downloads/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz -C /usr/include/
   ```

It's as easy as that - you now have Boost... but that's not all yet. Read on :)

**Building Boost.Python and Boost.System**

The Boost libraries Boost.Python and Boost.System must be *built* before they can be used. Here's how you do this:

1. Go into the Boost directory in your Terminal:

   ```
   cd /usr/include/boost_1_62_0/
   ```
2. Run the command:

   ```
   sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
   ```
3. To build Boost.Python and Boost.System into the `/usr/local/lib` folder, run:

   ```
   sudo ./b2 install --with-system --with-python
   ```

   once the command has finished, you will find `libboost_system` and `libboost_python` (with various file endings) in `/usr/local/lib`

That's it for building the necessary Boost libraries. Note that any other Boost library that needs to be built can be done in the same way.

**Preparing Python 2.7**

Linux Mint 18 comes with Python 2.7 pre-installed. For me, running the command `python --version` returns the output `Python 2.7.12`. I'll assume this is the same for you - but probably it doesn't make a difference what the version is. However, to get our objective of the C++ program with Boost.Python to build and run, you have to execute the additional command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

which places some additional necessary files (particularly `pyconfig.h`) into `/usr/include/python2.7`.

**Installing Linux GCC**

Linux GCC allows you to compile C++ programs. To install everything necessary, simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**Making our program run in Eclipse**

Now we've got everything configured to be able to write, build and run our program in Eclipse. So, let's do it!

1. Run Eclipse, either from the terminal (either by using the desktop icon we've created or by running `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` in the Terminal).
2. If it's your first time running Eclipse, you'll be prompted to choose a workspace (basically, a folder where all Eclipse project files will be stored):

[image]

3. Now go to File -> New -> C++ Project and enter the following and click Finish (you can use whatever Location you wish, including the default location (i.e. the one of your workspace)):

[image]

4. Now go to File -> New -> Source File, enter the following and click Finish:

[image]

5. In the `main.cpp` file that automatically opens in the editor, type in the program that we want to compile (note that I customized my Eclipse layout, so it looks different from the default layout you might have):

[image]

6. Now the secret sauce. Go to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings where you will see:

[image]

Go to GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes and, using the little icon that looks like a folder with a green plus sign, add the following Include paths:

[image]

Go to GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries and add the following Libraries and Library search paths:

[image]

Press OK to close the Project Properties window.

7. Back in the main Eclipse window, first click the hammer icon to build the project, then the green play icon to run it (both buttons are highlighted in the below screenshot). In the console view you will first see a successful build, then the Terminal output of our program:

[image]
[image]

That's it! We've achieved our objective of building and running a C++ program with the Boost.Python library included. That's the end of this tutorial, I hope it helped you :)